# How to pause and resume a thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading, pause

I make a thread to run a script, and it may spend much time. And I want to pause and resume it in another thread. If I use a flag and detect it, it can not pause immediately. I have searched a lot, but it seems that self.__flag, self.pause can not achieve the target.

```
class MT(threading.Thread):

    def __init__():
        self.__running = threading.Event()
        self.__running.set()
        self.__flag = threading.Event()
        self.__flag.set()

    def run(self):
        '''
        run the script
        '''
        while self.__running.isSet():
             self.__flag.wait()
             moudleTest()

    def pause(self):
        '''
        pause the thread
        '''
        self.__flag.clear()

    def resume(self):
        '''
        resume the thread
        '''
        self._-flag.set()
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not possible without diving below the Python layer using C extensions with OS specific techniques, e.g. on Windows, [`SuspendThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345(v=vs.85).aspx). You can not immediately and completely suspend another thread via Python level APIs, because doing so is considered absurdly dangerous.

Even when such a thing is possible, it's a terrible idea, prone to deadlocks and other terrible things. Just for example, pre-CPython 3.3, there was a single global import lock for the whole interpreter. If the other thread was in the middle of `import`ing a module when it was suspended, *no* other thread could import at all until it was resumed and finished the import (causing a deadlock if that thread was the one responsible for resuming the suspended thread); in CPython 3.3+, it's better, but if another thread tried to import that specific module, it would deadlock just as badly.

In summary: Use `Lock`s, `Event`s and/or `Condition`s appropriately, and if you need faster pauses, make the `wait` checks more often (interspersed with thread "work" more regularly). If your code can't tolerate even a tiny delay before the pause, you have a design problem that you need to fix (e.g. you're using `Event` to simulate locking or the like, possibly for performance, which is hilariously misguided, since `Event`s are built on `Condition`s which are in turn built on `Lock`s, and all but `Lock` are implemented at the Python layer, not the C layer, and therefore quite slow).